# Error when trying to boot my Linux using an USB and rEFInd

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, macintosh, refind

Some context I'm trying to dual boot Kali Linux and have followed Kali Linux's guide on how to do this.

I've successfully installed rEFInd but once rEFInd shows up, I plug in my bootable USB. It says *"BOOT legacy os whole disk"*. I think it's meant to say FAT instead of "whole" but when I select that option this happens...!
[An Error message of sorts but I can't explain it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYgrD.jpg)

I created the bootable USB using the DD method and various apps but nothing...
I'm sorry if I'm being a bit vague but the picture is basically the problem.

Comment: Did you check that you have the latest firmware update installed, like your screenshot suggests?

Comment: Yes I'm running high Sierra literally updated it two days ago thanks for the reply

Comment: Create bootable USB using `rufus`.

Comment: Hi I'll try that but why is Rufus different from all the others

Comment: Rufus is also for windows I'm using Mac

Comment: Which kali image did you burn to usb?

Answer (score 1):

I clicked the wrong option. I clicked the far left option instead of the one in the middle. I advise anyone that's doing this to not follow the Kali Linux guide on their website because it's wrong and outdated as I found out the hard way thanks for all your help. I'm afraid the problem was my own stupidity